# Hibernate Inner Join on Association Through Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Is there any way to force hibernate to use an inner-join for an association using annotations? I am using Hibernate 5 via Spring Boot JPA

```java
@Data
class Entity {
 private Integer id;

 @OneToMany
 @JoinColumn(name="entityId", referencedColumnName="id")
 private Set<ComplexObject> complexObjects;
```

I would like the join for `complexObjects` be an inner-join rather than a left join.

Comment: @Turing85 perhaps, but the type of join can also be representative of the relation. There's also annotations like `@Where` which directly impact the queries..

Comment: huh... didn't know that one :) My comments will self-destruct shortly

Comment: @aarbor Why do you decide that this is `left join`? If that would be true you should see multiple `null` in the `Set<ComplexObject>`.

Comment: You can use @Query to define your join in query.

Comment: @SternK if you log the queries you can see it will be left join. The objects won't be null, they will just be missing from the collection if they don't exist

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks I know I can do that, but the goal is to not have to manually redefine the queries

Comment: By default one-to-many is lazy, can you give me an example where is left joining?

Comment: @aarbor Is this unidirectional or bidirectional `@OneToMany` mapping?

Comment: @SternK unidirectional

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't see a join by default at all since this is a `@OneToMany` association which is lazy by default. There must be a query explictly using `LEFT JOIN FETCH` or  just `LEFT JOIN`. Other possible reasons for left joins to happen are the use of an entity graph or the use of the `fetch` method in the JPA CriteriaBuilder API.

In general, the left join here is correct as it is necessary to retain the expected cardinality. Fetching with an inner join would eliminate the main entity if there were no children which is probably not what one would expect when applying e.g. an entity graph.

I don't understand why you need an `INNER JOIN`, but depending on how the join is created, you might have to adapt your query to get the desired result.

Comment: You're right I am using entity graphs. The reason I wanted the inner join is to join to a `roles` table, so it would only include the main entities which the user has access to. I think I'll end up having to use a `@Filter` getting applied with AOP instead

Comment: In that case, I'd consider this being "business logic" so you should encode that in the query.

Comment: I ended up using a `@Filter` w/ Spring AOP to intercept calls in the relevant services and add the filter to the hibernate session. I still think this should be easier to do in Hibernate though

Comment: It is easy, you just have to adapt the query ;)